# Offer user the option to re-run code

Tags: python

```
print ("Welcome to my Area Calculator")
i=raw_input("Please enter the shape whose Area you want to calculate(square/rectangle/right angled triangle/rhombus/parallelogram): ")
my_list=["square","rectangle","triangle","right angled triangle","rhombus","parallelogram"]
if i in my_list:
   if i=="square":
       s=float(input("What is the side of the square: "))
       print "Area of the square is : ", s**2
   elif i=="rectangle":
       l=float(input("What is the length of the rectangle: "))
       b=float(input("What is the breadth of the rectangle: "))
       print "Area of the rectangle is : ", l*b

   elif i=="right angled triangle":
       base1=float(input("What is the base of the triangle: "))
       height1=float(input("What is the height of the triangle: "))
       print "Area of the triangle is : ", 0.5*base1*height1
   elif i=="rhombus":
       d1=float(input("What is the length of the 1st diagnol of the rhombus: "))
       d2=float(input("What is the length of the 2nd diagnol of the rhombus: "))
       print "Area of the rhombus is : ", 0.5*d1*d2
   elif i=="parallelogram":
       base=float(input("What is the length of 1 side of the parallelogram: "))
       height=float(input("What is the length of the other side: "))
       print "Area of the parallelogram is : ", height*base
   print "Thank you so much for using my area calculator"
```

Answer (score 2):

Make your entire program became a function, then execute it inside while loop.

```
while(option != 'yes'):
   Program()
   userInput()
```

Answer (score 0):

Ask for the user if he wants to continue, put it in a boolean variable, put all your code in a while loop with this boolean as a condition
Don't forget to init this boolean to true